# How to bypass non html IPs via BeautifulSoup scraping through an IP address scan

Tags: beautifulsoup, ip

Right now I am just trying to pull links through a range of IP address using BeautifulSoup.  However, it seems to crash when the IP address is not html.  Any suggestions to bypass IP addresses in the loop that are not html?

```
start_ip = ipaddress.IPv4Address(u'170.217.10.0')
end_ip = ipaddress.IPv4Address(u'172.217.10.142')
for ip_int in range(int(start_ip), int(end_ip)):
    ip = ipaddress.IPv4Address(ip_int)
    print ip
    r  = requests.get("http://" + str(ip))
    data = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        print(link.get('href'))
```

**Results**

```
170.217.10.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "web_scraper.py", line 16, in <module>
    r  = requests.get("http://" + str(ip))
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 603, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 355, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1042, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1082, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1038, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 882, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 844, in send
    self.connect()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 183, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 160, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 70, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
```

Comment: what are the imports used?

Comment: from bs4 BeautifulSoup, requests,ipaddress